# Why can't I set a default value for a function parameter of <map> type?

Tags: c++

Below is my sample program that won't compile.  I want to create a function that takes a map as a possible argument, but provides a default empty map if one isn't supplied.  Pretty straight forward, just not sure why it doesn't work.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl; using std::map;

int func(map<int, int>& = map<int, int>());

int main() {
    map<int, int> m;
    m[2] = 4;

    cout << "func() = " << func() << endl;   // "func() = 0"
    cout << "func(m) = " << func(m) << endl; // "func(m) = 1"
}

int func(map<int, int>& m) { return m.size(); }
```

The compiler error I get is:

```
test.cc:6:42: error: default argument for 'std::map<int, int>& <anonymous>' has type 'std::map<int, int>'
```

Please explain, it doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may bind temporary objects with constant references. So the function might be declared as

```
int func( const map<int, int>& = map<int, int>());
```

Comment: Well, in this example, that would work.  In the place where I intended to use this, I was actually trying to add values to the map inside the function and then return a copy.  Suppose instead that the function was `map<int,int> func(map<int, int>& m) { m[3] = 6; return m; }`.  Adding const to the parameter would cause this to fail.

Comment: I guess I could do `map<int,int> func(const map<int, int>& m) { map<int, int> mm = m; mm[3] = 6; return mm; }` But that would require an additional unnecessary copy (mm=m and return mm) instead of just (return m).